# How to remove string which comes after special string each line

Tags: python

I try to convert text to new_text using python.
I couldn't match after 'metamorphemes=' in the below sentences. how can I do that?

```
text = "I have no idea about metamorphemes=sentence. I have idea about metamorphemes=python."
```

**Output**

```
new_text = "I have no idea about. I have idea about."
```

Comment: try regex module

Comment: i tried but couldn't find the soultion. @BeliaevMaksim

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.sub`, we can remove the key=value pair from each sentence:

```py
text = "I have no idea about metamorphemes=sentence. I have idea about metamorphemes=python."
output = re.sub(r'\s*\w+=\w+', '', text)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
I have no idea about. I have idea about.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
text = "I have no idea about metamorphemes=sentence. I have idea about metamorphemes=python."

pattern = re.compile(r"\s*metamorphemes=\w+\b")

new_text = pattern.sub('', text)
print(new_text)
```

**Output**

```
I have no idea about. I have idea about.
```

Note that this **only** removes patterns that have `metamorphemes=` as a prefix.